# Tuning the "frequency corners" of a PID system (with two integrals)

Tags: rf, pid-controller, optics

I am having some trouble understanding the language used in control theory.

I have a laser that is set up in a "Pound-drever-Hall" lock. This lock basically sets up a feedback loop between the electrical input controlling a piezo in a mechanical system, and an voltage output "error signal" that is sent a PID controller. (For more details on the setup, check out an [older question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37733/differential-equation-for-locking-a-lasers-frequency-with-a-pi-controller/37737#37737) of mine)

My PID controller is made specifically for these kinds of locks. And on the side there is a picture of the "corners" of the gain of the controller.

Here's a picture of the controller:

[image]

I can control the "proportional gain" by turning a knob in the front. And there are fixed discrete switches I can turn that let me change the location of the "corners" for the gain response of the controller for the integral and differential parts.

How do I tune such a device? I'm familiar with the [Ziegler-Nichols tuning method](http://www.mstarlabs.com/control/znrule.html), but for that you're simply changing the gain values, not the values of the "frequency corners."

Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: "**My PID controller is made specifically for these kinds of locks." Does it have a user manual ?

Comment: [here](https://www.vescent.com/products/electronics/d2-125-laser-servo/)